# Printf adding extra space in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, printf

I am writing a shell script to create file and write multiple lines to it.

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENTHOST="$(hostname -I)"
touch genesis_start.sh
printf '%s\n\t''--http-server-address '"$CURRENTHOST"':8888 \' >> genesis_start.sh
```

There are more lines but I am just showing one.
The above code looks like in `genesis_start.sh` file:

```
--http-server-address 192.168.110.164 :8888 \
```

The extra space is added between `164` and `8888`. How to display it without space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will always be space after the IP address, however, you can remove it like this :

```
CURRENTOST=${CURRENTHOST::-1}
```

Reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144298/delete-the-last-character-of-a-string-using-string-manipulation-in-shell-script

Comment: `There will always be space after the IP address,...` why?

Comment: I really don't have deep knowledge about this, but this is how the command's coding was done. Maybe we could find something in it's original documentation?

Comment: Well, I don't get a space after my IP. `printf "%s:\n" $(hostname -I)` gives `192.168.1.24:`

Answer (score 1):

Your code quality would really benefit from the help of the shellcheck.net linter.

There are many issues bugs with your script:

- Misuse of `printf` (constant parts and variable formatter should go to the format string, there must be at least as many variable arguments as variable formatters)
- Invalid escaping of single quote.
- Wrong parsing of `hostname -I` which can return multiple space delimited entries.

Fixed your code:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Get the first IP address only
read -r CURRENTHOST _ < <(hostname -I)

printf '\t--http-server-address %s:8888\n' "$CURRENTHOST" > genesis_start.sh
```